# Google Test Framework does not print std::optional

Tags: c++, c++17, googletest, googlemock

I have a data structure which is being notified to a listener. Among its many variables, it has an optional double which represents an angle:

```
struct Data
{
    // ...other data fields
    std::optional<double> angle;
    // ...other data fields
};
```

I want to check that the listener is being called with the right `angle`. I am using the **Google Test Framework**, so I have defined my own matcher here:

```
MATCHER_P( HasAngle, angle, "" )
{
    if ( !arg.angle.has_value( ) )
    {
        return false;
    }

    return arg.angle.value( ) == angle;
}
```

And checked if my listener is being called with the expected value.

```
EXPECT_CALL( listener, on_event( HasAngle( 45.0 ) ) ).Times( AtLeast( 1 ) );
```

It ended up that the listener is not called with the expected value, but the printouts are really unreadable:

```
  Expected arg #0: has angle 45
       Actual: 128-byte object <75-85 4D-52 FB-21 F9-BF 47-D9 48-53 FB-21 09-C0 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 01-17 23-83 FD-7F 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00>
```

The actual value is unintelligible. I was not expecting the framework to not support C++17 types by default, so I started reading the **Google Test Framework Cookbook** and I tried to add my own `PrintTo` overload like this:

```
void
PrintTo( const std::optional< double >& opt, std::ostream* os )
{
    if ( !opt )
    {
        *os << "std::nullopt";
    }
    else
    {
        *os << *opt;
    }
}
```

Needless to say, it did not help. What I am pretty much sure is that since the output states `128-byte object` it is trying to print the sole `std::optional<double>` and not the entire `struct Data`, which is much bigger than that, but it is not succeeding despite the overloaded `PrintTo`.

Comment: What version of googletest are you using? [this](https://github.com/google/googletest/pull/2438/files) might be relevant.

Comment: Actually, the comment above is an early PR that was originally rejected. It appears to be finally merged [here](https://github.com/google/googletest/commit/07d4a6e93de43ab47f5a5a3994009f53360e06c8) (June 2020)...

Comment: @BennyK it is version 1.10.0

Answer (score 6):

GoogleTest does print `std::optional` values, if you use the [`Optional(m)`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/652ec31f9f53ab34af1257e5e2783d77e872ed45/docs/reference/matchers.md#generic-comparison) matcher.

Example test:

```
TEST_F(MyClassTests, myFunctionTest)
{
    std::optional<std::string> actual_value = "foo";
    std::string expected_value = "bar";

    EXPECT_THAT(actual_value, testing::Optional(expected_value));
}
```

The output will be similar, but after the *cryptic* `128-byte object <75-85 4D-52 FB-21 F9-BF...` text, the contained value will be printed additionally:

```
...
[ RUN      ] MyClassTests.myFunctionTest
myclasstests.cpp:123: Failure
Value of: actual_value
Expected: value is equal to "bar"
  Actual: 40-byte object <DE-AD BE-EF CA-FE BA-BE ...>, whose value "foo" doesn't match
[  FAILED  ] MyClassTests.myFunctionTest (0 ms)
...
```

---

If you expect a `std::optional` to be `std::nullopt` in a testcase, you will most probably do it with:

```
EXPECT_EQ(actual_value, std::nullopt);
```

The test will fail, if `actual_value` actually has a value. But again, the actual value will not be printed. As a workaround, you can implement the test like this:

```
if (actual_value) {
    FAIL() << "actual_value is not std::nullopt, but: " << actual_value.value();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Definition of standard output operator for your type in the test should help and be used in gmock error messages

```
template <class T>
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, std::optional<T> const & opt)
{
  if (opt) return os << opt.value();
  return os << "EMPTY";
}
```

Comment: Correct one for own created types, for std::optional https://stackoverflow.com/a/69132532/2522849 is the better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt does not work as it is a `std::` type. You would have to define the PrintTo in `std` namespace according to [documentation](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/google/googletest/+/HEAD/googletest/docs/advanced.md)

> // If you can't declare the function in the class it's important that
> PrintTo() // is defined in the SAME namespace that defines Bar.  C++'s
> look-up rules rely // on that.

So I would expect the following to work (if included before the google test framework):

```
namespace std {
void
PrintTo( const optional< double >& opt, std::ostream* os )
{
    if ( !opt )
    {
        *os << "std::nullopt";
    }
    else
    {
        *os << *opt;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I tried this as well, I am aware of ADL, but for some reason this does not work as well

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 are you sure you are including this stuff before the framework is included/used ?

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 another thing is you can test the printing with ::testing::PrintToString(x)

Answer (score 1):

You're worrying about the wrong type.  Your `struct Data` is the result being tested, not a `std::optional<double>`.  That's why your code has `arg.angle`, because `arg` is a `Data`.  Define a stream insertion operator for `Data`, then gtest will use it.